# Wrapper class' validation based on an Existing checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, wrapper-class

I am trying to implement a validation check before processing the selected record(s) from my Wrapper class's list.  Here I am checking for one checkbox's value before processing the selected records(from Wrapper list).

**Logic I am trying to implement**:
Once we have selected a record(or records) from the list, if one of them has the flag checkbox enabled, then I should get an alert and further processing shouldn't take place.

Here is what I've implemented.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Select Records" onclick="validation(); return false;" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
...
<apex:column >
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="wrapperCheckbox"/>
</apex:column>
...
<apex:column headerValue="Processed Contact">
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.processed}" disabled="true" id="processFlag"/>
</apex:column>
...
<apex:actionFunction name="Process1" action="{!selContacts}" id="selectionProcess" reRender="form"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="Process2" action="{!status}" id="spinner" status="pagestatus" reRender="form" />
...
...
<script>
function validation(){
    if(!document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=wrapperCheckbox]:checked').length){
        confirm('Please select at least one Contact'); 
        return false; 
    } else{
        if(confirm('Do you want to proceed with the processing?')){ 
            processing();
            return false;
        }
    }     
}

function processing(){
    if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=wrapperCheckbox]:checked') && document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=processFlag]:checked')){
        alert('Size: ' +document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=wrapperCheckbox]:checked').length);
        alert('Cannot process this request as the record was previously processed');
    } else{
        Process1();
        Process2();
        window.top.location='/{!Contact.Id}'; 
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I am not able to get the validation work. 
How can I have the client-side validation rule to work for each of the rows(based on my criteria)? Implementing this via Server-side is too complicated and time consuming.

Comment: Use your browser's "Inspect" feature to see what the `id="wrapperCheckbox"` Id is converted to; think it will include a row number that probably causes your id match to fail. Can be simpler to match to a marker class name that you add.

Comment: @KeithC I've tried to display the size of both the checkboxes using alert. It seemed to be getting accurate length based on my selection. Here I am getting values of overall list of records, and not comparing the each record. Is there any way I can compare each row's checkboxes and get the validations?

Comment: Based on your "Logic I am trying to implement" you could just check if the length is greater than zero i.e. `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=wrapperCheckbox]:checked').length > 0`. But if you want to look at each checkbox, loop` and  over `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][id*=wrapperCheckbox]')` and use one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, just a question: Can we do this without using the jQuery?

Comment: Yes for these browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll. The days of needing jQuery to paper over browser incompatibilities are more or less over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving a validation error after selecting the checkbox, why don't you disable it during rendering of the page. If the `processed` flag is true you can disable the `selected` checkbox. So you don't need any validation as user will not able to select it.

The highlight of the code is **disabled="{!wrapC.processed}"**. Based on the processed flag value, the selected checkbox is enabled or disabled.

VF Code

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapList}" var="wrapC" >
        <apex:column >
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapC.selected}" disabled="{!wrapC.processed}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapC.processed}" disabled="true"/>
        </apex:column>                
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Looks great. I will implement this and keep you posted.

Comment: So I've followed your approach and it seemed working. This is what I have implemented: `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="wrapperCheckbox" disabled="{!(OR(c.processed1, c.processed2))}"/>`. I had two check-boxes to consider, so used an **OR** condition and it worked. I will mark this as a solution if no one can help me with the actual (validation check) approach I am looking for.